# MySQL connection ('max_user_connections')

Tags: php, mysql

I can not access my database. I'm getting the following error:

```
 User 'myuser' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 5)
```

In my PHP code every open connection is closed next. And, as I know, when PHP script finishes, the connection is closed automatically.

Is there any way to restart the server or close all connections remotely?

Comment: 5? That's awful low. You may want to raise the max connections for that user.

Comment: Definitely consider increasing the max connections unless you'll only have one or two users accessing the application at a time.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections For more information on the variable in your error message

Answer (score 0):

This should work on linux for restarting your mysql server

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL configuration file, set

```
max_connections=200
```

5 is too low.  You will need to restart the server. If you can't restart, make this setting in the config file and execute this in the workbench

```
set global max_connections=200
```

Comment: max_connections is for overall, max_user_connections (as noted in the error) is per user.

Comment: In web app scenarios, there is only one user

Comment: Exactly. The error message says max_user_connections, so changing max_connections will not help. They're two different settings.

Comment: @aynber do you have a user setup in mysql for everyone that visits the site?

Comment: No, I have one user per website. One mysql user that does all of the querying. I just checked my own server, and I've seen 7 queries from the one mysql user. I know I've seen it up to 20 or more when the site gets really busy.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance, but the server is remote, how can I access the mySQL configuration file?

Comment: If you have one user per website, then use use `max_connections`

Comment: It's usually in `/etc/my.conf` or `/etc/mysql/my.conf`. If you don't have access to it. You'll need to talk to your webhost.

Comment: @BrenoMacena if you don't have any admin access to the DB server using workbench or similar, you may try to make a call from PHP to "set global max_connections" (just like you would call an stored procedure,  but I am not sure.